# "Cannot bulk load. Sort order incorrect..." while rebuilding index partition

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

We are running Ola Hallengrens database maintenance scripts against several databases in Azure.
The last few week we ran into the same error on execution. It persists if we execute the command on our own.

The table is versioned, and partitioned on a computed column. Both were recently added around the time the error first appeared.

Command:

> ALTER INDEX [IX_AdvertisementUnits_LastModified] ON [dbo].[AdvertisementUnits] REBUILD PARTITION = 46 WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, ONLINE = ON, RESUMABLE = OFF)

Error message:

> Cannot bulk load. The bulk data stream was incorrectly specified as sorted or the data violates a uniqueness constraint imposed by the target table. Sort order incorrect for the following two rows: primary key of first row: (2020-06-10 17:37:00.7631521 +02:00, 2020-03-02, 2020-03-03, 37414493), primary key of second row: (2020-04-05 19:10:25.4284962 +02:00, 2020-04-06, 2020-04-05, 38193312).

Azure compatibility_level: 140

I could not find any solution that got close to our problem, I have not tried to rebuild the entire index because I might lose the ability to reproduce the problem.

Comment: In looking at the Ola Hallengrens solution, it has a wide supportability footprint, including Azure SQL Database: https://ola.hallengren.com/downloads.html. Did you set this up with the larger MaintenanceSolution.sql script or did you use one of the specific scripts (IndexOptimize.sql as an example) to create a specific maintenance task?

Comment: The `MaintenanceSolution.sql` script will not work for Azure SQL Database. It is not listed as a supported server type, and by running a parse of the script, I get the following: Msg 40515, Level 15, State 1, Procedure DatabaseBackup, Line 16 [Batch Start Line 363]
Reference to database and/or server name in 'msdb.dbo.backupset' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.
Msg 40515, Level 15, State 1, Line 8680
Reference to database and/or server name in 'msdb.dbo.sysjobs' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Completion time: 2020-06-19T11:06:51.2290514-07:00

Comment: Thank you for your Feedback, I used the individual Scripts for IndexOptimize,CommandLog etc.

Comment: The error can be circumvented by using the  @PartitionLevel = N'N', option in IndexOptimize.
So far I have only found that this index was the only one newly added to the partitioned table. The only difference to other working indexes is that this one misses 'ON [PRIMARY]' at the end.
Creating the database empty correctly creates a non partitioned index. but that is an ef core question for another time.

Comment: I would like to focus this question more on the sql aspect and this specific error. So not why tha index was created in this why but how to fix this an the source for this error.

Comment: In the end we just recreated the index with 'on [primary]' so the index is not partitioned. This "solved" the problem since the index should not have been partitioned in the first place.
No new insights for this exception though.

Comment: @SteveMeyer congratulations you solved the issue in the end. I just help you post it as an answer. You may think about accept(mark) it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. You also could post it by yourself with more details, I will delete mine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations you solved the issue in the end:

"In the end we just recreated the index with 'on [primary]' so the index is not partitioned. This "solved" the problem since the index should not have been partitioned in the first place."

@Steve Meyer provided more details in the comments.

I help you post it as an answer and this can be beneficial to other community members.